# Converting between date formats in PHP giving error

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, calendar

database date format that i retrieve is

```
 $event_date='2013-01-20';
```

and i want to convert this format to like this
    Jan 1,2013

I have tried this

```
echo date('M d, Y',$event_date)
//but it is printing wrong value "Jan 01, 1970"
```

and giving error also:  ***Notice (8): A non well formed numeric value encountered***

if anyone can catch please help me to get correct value

Comment: @MarkBaker sir your comment may be according to title not according to question.... i have described well my question and my try... it's your choice you want to close it or not..you have rights you can do it to improve your power!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: and which part of the accepted answer to the question I linked doesn't answer your own question?

Comment: @MarkBaker may be anser same but not question...i already did know my answer but i was just missing a method strtotime ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use [**`strtotime()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function to correctly format the date since `date()` function expects second parameter to be a timestamp

```
echo date('M d, Y',strtotime($event_date));
```

From documentation

> The function expects to be given a string containing an English date format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC), relative to the timestamp given in now, or the current time if now is not supplied.

Live working sample [**here**](http://codepad.org/ZjaOeamG)

Answer (score 2):

`date` expects second parameter to be a timestamp http://php.net/date

http://php.net/strtotime is the way to go.

`date('M d, Y', strtotime($event_date))`

Answer (score 1):

You should do:

```
echo date('M d, Y',strtotime($event_date));
```

Answer (score 1):

try this....

```
echo date('M d, Y',strtotime($event_date));
```

Answer (score 1):

Do like below

```
<?php  $event_date='2013-01-20';
echo date('M d, Y',  strtotime($event_date));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) to convert the Dateformat

```
   <?php
    $event_date='2013-01-20';
    $date = new DateTime($event_date);
    echo $date->format('M d, Y');
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$event_date='2013-01-20';

echo date('M d, Y',strtotime($event_date));
```